# Issue getting time zone

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
input(strftime("%z", gmtime()))
```

Output: -0000

I'm trying to get this specifically:
GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)
(This is my timezone)
i'm trying to get this exact/specific layout but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone    

ireland = timezone('Etc/GMT-1')
ir_time = datetime.now(ireland)
print (ir_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

you can change the timezone to whatever you want.
i used the timezone module and the normal datetime module

Comment: Do you know an alternative where the OP doesn't need to install pytz?

Comment: @LucasVazquez no i this was the only thing i could come up with right now

Comment: @Tarun thanks for the reply, although this info might be inaccurate if someone else got their hands on this code, i want it to get it from wherever they are

Answer (score 0):

`gmtime` won't give you time in your local time zone, so I would suggest using `localtime`.

I think this should work:

`strftime("GMT %z (%Z)", localtime())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you expected, but I think it's can work

```py
# Also, I don't know what version of python you are using, but this works for python 2 and 3
import time
print("GMT" + time.strftime("%Z", time.gmtime()).ljust(5, '0'))

# Returns "GMT-0300" in my case
```

If you can, give more example or a better explanation

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```py
import requests
json = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json').json()
timezone = json['timezone']
print(timezone)
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way of not doing it with requests?

Comment: I don't know. I use `requests` for this, but there's gotta be another way.